# get() on ObservableFields in an expression

Tags: android, lambda, data-binding, kotlin, android-databinding

I have a fairly simple layout with Databinding:

```
<data>
    <variable
        name="viewModel"
        type="MyViewModel" />

    <variable
        name="navigator"
        type="MyNavigator" />
</data>

<Button
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:onClick="@{() -> navigator.goto(viewModel.insurance, viewModel.title)}"
    android:text="Click">
```

Here's the viewModel in Kotlin:

```
class MyViewModel {
    val title = ObservableInt()
    val insurance = ObservableField<Insurance?>()
}
```

And here's the Navigator in Kotlin:

```
class MyNavigator(private val activity: MyActivity) {

    fun goto(insurance: Insurance?, @StringRes title: Int) {
        if (insurance != null) {
            val intent = OtherActivity.newIntent(activity, insurance,title)
            activity.startActivity(intent)
        } else {
            Timber.w("goToClaimsQuestionsList but no insurance")
        }
    }
}
```

**Expected:**

When I click the button, the Navigator should receive the event, and launch another activity. **However, `insurance Insurance?` is always null**.

When I use this expression in the layout (using `.get()`):

```
android:onClick="@{() -> navigator.goto(viewModel.insurance.get(), viewModel.title.get())}"
```

**all works as expected**, but I receive a warning while building:

> Warning:warning: Do not explicitly call 'get()' on ObservasbleFields in an expression. This support will be removed soon. 'viewModel.insurance.get()'

Is this a bug in the current Databinding implementation with Kotlin? Or is there another explanation of why I have to use `ObservableField.get()` ?

NOTE:

- AndroidStudio 3.0 for Mac
- buildToolsVersion: 27.0.3
- android gradle plugin: 3.0.1
- kotlinVersion: 1.2.21

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears to be a [bug](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/70139194) not related to *Kotlin*.

But in your case one could argue, that it might be better not to use it from the the XML layer at all.

Instead you could create a variable with callbacks to encapsulate the navigation logic

```
class Callbacks(val vm: MyViewModel, val navigator: MyNavigator) {
    fun buttonClicked() = navigator.goto(vm.insurance.get(), vm.title.get())
}
```

and call this function `onClick`

```
android:onClick="@{() -> callbacks.buttonClicked())}"
```

Comment: Thanks. I still wonder what's different about this expression. It seems that 99% of the time, for my codebase, i do NOT need the `.get()`. But for some reason, I do need it in this expression.

Comment: Appears the bug has been fixed.